# Thread 1 reads from file as thread 2 writes to same file

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, file

Thread 1 (T1) creates the file using

```
FILE *MyFile = tmpfile();
```

Thread 2 (T2) then starts writing to the file. While thread 2 is writing, thread 1 occasionally reads from the file.

I set it up such that T2 is temporarily suspended when T1 is reading but, as T1 is only ever reading part of the file T2 won't be writing to (the file is written sequentially), I'm wondering if suspending T2 is necessary. I know this would be OK if FILE was replaced by fixed size array / vector. Just wondering how disc differs from memory.

Edit.

The writes are done using fseek and fwrite. The reads are done using fseek and fread. I assumed that was a given but maybe not from some of the comments. I suppose if T1 fseeks to position X at the same time as T2 fseeks to position Y then who knows where the next read or write will start from. Will take a look at pipes, Thanks for the help.

Comment: Even sharing memory between threads can lead to undefined behavior when your second thread is modifying the memory while thread 1 is watching it. It is possible for thread 1 to see a 'half state' (i.e. read while thread 2 is still busy writing things to memory).

You would need something like a mutex to ensure only one thread is accessing it at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited my question to read FIXED size array / vector. Re the FILE, is it possible to read and write at the same time? Will the disc OS not receive requests like write, write, write, read, write … and deal with them in the order they arrive?

Comment: File read/write is related to the disk I/O, as stack/heap to memory. T1 and T2 can mutually exclude each other by using a lock.

Comment: Not a good idea. Files are very difficult to use as a form of IPC. If you need a database, use a database.

Comment: suspend threads not need and senseless. and you need use `ReadFile`, `WriteFile` api with explicit ofset to read/write

Comment: If you need to pass data, use a tool designed to *pass* data, such as a pipe.  Not one designed to *store/save* data.

Comment: Fixing the array size may help against invalid pointer values (since you are not reallocating the memory over and over). But it does not help against data races. What I mean is that T1 may be looking at the memory while T2 is still in the middle of writing it. This can (and will) happen at the same time! You can end up reading inconsistent data.

Comment: @E. van Putten. Agreed, but in this case T1 checks where T2 has populated up to and doesn't request anything beyond that point. Probably another thing I should have pointed out in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixing reads and writes on a FILE is not even safe when dealing with a single thread. From the manpage of fopen:

> Reads and writes may be intermixed on read/write streams in  any  order.   Note  that  ANSI  C
>          requires  that a file positioning function intervene between output and input, unless an input
>          operation encounters end-of-file.  (If this condition is not met, then a read  is  allowed  to
>          return  the  result of writes other than the most recent.)  Therefore it is good practice (and
>          indeed sometimes necessary under Linux) to put an fseek(3)  or  fgetpos(3)  operation  between
>          write  and  read  operations on such a stream.  This operation may be an apparent no-op (as in
>          fseek(..., 0L, SEEK_CUR) called for its synchronizing side effect).

So don't assume reads and writes are magically synchronized for you and protect access to the FILE with a mutex.

Comment: But what if he opens the file twice? I can see both the producer and consumer both opening the file with share flags. But I agree with @Andrew Henle who says it's better to use a pipe. OP is using Windows so he can even open the pipe in message mode so he doesn't even have to split the stream of incoming bytes into separate messages...

Comment: That is even worse because then you have 2 FILE streams with separate buffers. A write in one FILE wouldn't show up in the other FILE unless it is flushed to disk. And yes, a pipe is better for communicating between threads.